# How can I put alerts in navbar when using Bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am studying bootstrap, and build a site using this example:`http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/hero.html`

I want to show alerts in the navbar. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you want. You can use [labels and badges](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#labels-badges) to show short message or number of notifications with a link to separate page. Or you can attach [tooltip](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tooltips) or [popover](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#popovers) to it. E.g.

```
<a href="#" 
   data-html="true"
   data-placement="bottom"
   data-toggle="popover"
   data-content="Notification 1<br/>Notification 2"
   data-original-title="Notifications">
    <span class="badge badge-success">2</span> Notifications
</a>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WBTf8/22/

Comment: Any ideas of how to put a notification on the "hamburger"/icon-bar part? So that users know there is an alert without having to click on the icon-bars.

Answer (score 0):

Use dropdown navigation for this...

**Check this,**

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navs

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#navbar

Thanks